# Codeigniter URI routing is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

I am using codeigniter framework in my web development and passing the value of image id using php code such below

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('account/gallery/view'); ?>?id=<?php echo $imageDetail['imageId']; ?>">
    <img src="" />
</a>
```

and getting the value at controller with this code `$imageId = $this->input->get('id');`

With the `get` method I used, it will display the url like this :

`http://my-domain-name/account/gallery/view?id=1`

But I want to display the url like this :

`http://my-domain-name/account/gallery/1`

So what I did is setting in the router with this code but it's not working.

`$route['account/gallery/(:num)'] = 'default/Gallery_controller/view/$1';`

My web still able to show the template of the web if I type `http://my-domain-name/account/gallery/1` but display error in the field that I fetch from database because unable to get the `imageId`

Comment: Just curious - are you saying that you had $route['account/gallery/(:num)'] = 'default/Gallery_controller/view?id=$1'; working? Or did you add in that route after you had it working with your initial URL?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I had it working with routing `$route['account/gallery/(:num)'] = 'default/Gallery_controller/view/$1';` where template of my website is viewable but all field which value that I fetch from database display error because with the routing I set making my web unable to get the value of image id

Comment: @LinundusOndu, Check My answer, [it's here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696387/2679536)

Comment: Can you share what the error is?

Comment: ok so if you have in your case the url pattern folder/controller/method/id you can, as has been mentioned here, set function view($id) {...} OR you can grab it using the $this->url->segment(x), where x is the segment number and in your case x is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Regex instead of `:num` in route.php

```
$route['account/gallery/([0-9]+)'] = 'default/Gallery_controller/view/$1';
```

And in your template file:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('account/gallery/'.$imageDetail['imageId']); ?>">
    <img src="" />
</a>
```

Then you can access directly in your gallary controller in view function `$id`.

eg:

```
class Gallery extends MY_Controller {
     public function view($id){
       // Your Image ID = $id;
  }
}
```

Comment: After all those struggle, finally I get it working with your solution. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Anytime to help in CodeIgniter!!

Comment: Hi Shaunak, can I ask another question? How do I redirect user to `http://my-domain-name/account/gallery/1` if they are trying to type anything like `http://my-domain-name/account/gallery/view?id=1` ?

Comment: I prefer to say to show '404 - Page Not Found' because CodeIgniter will not support query string and global variable like $_GET along with SEO based URL structure. If we try to make so, We have to choose either. So it's better not to redirect. Another thing, Why should we give user chance to manipulate site URLs?

Answer (score 0):

> Set this url  http://my-domain-name/account/gallery/1 proper in href

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('account/gallery/view'.$imageDetail['imageId']); ?>">
    <img src="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('account/gallery/view'); ?>?id=<?php echo $imageDetail['imageId']; ?>">
```

with

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>account/gallery/view/<?php echo $imageDetail['imageId']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.php

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;
```

to

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this try this `(:any)`

```
$route['account/gallery/(:any)'] = 'default/gallery_controller/view/$1';
```

Or

```
$route['account/gallery/view?(:any)'] = 'default/gallery_controller/view/$1';
```

In the routes lower case

Answer (score 0):

This code is make your url like http://domain-name/account/gallery/1

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>account/gallery/view/<?php echo $imageDetail['imageId'];?>">
    <img src="" />
</a>
```